# how to add cache control header with proxy pass in nginx for some file extensions

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, cache-control, nginx-config

I like add cache control header with nginx for some extensions such as .jpg, etc but so far some of the solutions I found on the net, I couldn't get it to work. I will tell you what I have tried.

I have tried variations of the following in different place in the .conf file of my site and when I tried the site become blank and I found a lot of 404 errors on the console. The site is developed in React.

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 1d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
}
```

My conf file looks like the following. The thing is I have to do reverse proxy as the sites are actually hosted in Docker containers.

```
 server {
    server_name mysite.net;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:3005/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;

        proxy_pass  http://api:5005/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect    off;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;
        proxy_read_timeout 1200;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.net-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.net-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = mysite.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `map` directive:

```
map $cache $control {
    1       "public, no-transform";
}

map $cache $expires {
    1       1d;
    default off; # or some other default value
}

map $uri $cache {
    ~*\.(js|css|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$    1;
}

server {
    ...
    expires $expires;
    add_header Cache-Control $control;
    ...
}
```

(you can also put `expires` and `add_header` directives into the `location` context or even leave then in the `http` context). nginx won't add the header at all (or modify an existing header) if the value calculated via the map expression for `$control` variable will be an empty string. This is not the only possible solution, you can also rely on the `Content-Type` response header from your upstream (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972168/how-to-cache-nextjs-10-0-images-using-nginx/64987300#64987300) answer for an example).

You should be aware of [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) documentation excerpt:

> There could be several `add_header` directives. These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.